# How to receive realtime notification when a certain user posts picture in instagram with PHP API

Tags: php, instagram-api

Recently, I started doing a little project with this http://elogram.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

It is an instagram API library.

I have learnt how to do lots of things with the library, but am having a little issue here.

I am trying to build a web app that will perhaps receive a notification from instagram, and automatically pull the latest post details of a user I subscribed to, from instagram and save to my Database.

I can be able to pull of data from an account I created for the purpose, what I want is a kind of system where

1. I subscribe to @exampleuser on instagram
2. @exampleuser posts a picture or video on instagram
3. Instagram sends notification, my server catches the push notification
4. My app will check against database if the post exists, if it doesn't exist, then it gets inserted into the database.

I don't know how to achieve that.

Here is a little snippet from my work, am working with Slim Framework.

```
        $app->get('/new/getfrominsta', function () use ($app) {

        $clientId = getenv('CLIENT_ID');
        $clientSecret =$_ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'];
        $redirectUrl = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI'];


        $client = new Client($clientId, $clientSecret, $MyAccessToken, $redirectUrl); //use existing token to instantiate client class
        $g= $client->users()->getMedia('1234567'); //1234567 is ID of user I intend to get his post
        $self2 = json_encode($g->get());


        foreach($self2 as $instapost)
        {
            $imgURL = $instapost->images->standard_resolution->url;
            $InstaPostID = $instapost->link;

            //$checkIfInstaPostExists = $InstaModel->CheckIfInstaPostExists($InstaPostID, $imgURL); //check if post in loop already exists in db.


            print_r($instapost);
            echo "<br/>";

        }
        exit();
    });
```

With this I can get the users' recent 20 media posts, because of sandbox mode.

What I want is how to implement the User Subscription Notification.

Answer (score 0):

[What you  unclear here?](https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/)

> When we have new updates to send your server, we do a simple POST with a payload containing updates to a URL on your server. This callback URL must support GET and POST methods.
>
> When you add a subscription, we will send a GET request to your callback URL to verify the existence of the URL. When we have new data, we'll POST this data to your callback URL. We'll explain more about what this URL needs to do later on this page.

Comment: I have read the developers documentation, I kind of need an example of how it works.

Comment: You need send POST request with data specified in dev doc.